# placeholder para varchar sql

Tags: python, sqlite

Estou a fazer um programa que lê o output do Arduino e envia para uma base de dados SQLITE3.

Está-me a dar este erro:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO reciclagem_data (personID, nome) VALUES (%s,%s)", (pieces[0], pieces[1]))
OperationalError: near "%": syntax error
```

personID é o UID de um cartão RFID e o nome é simplesmente o nome.

 Pesquisei e encontrei que o melhor tipo de data para o UID seria varchar. Penso que o erro tenha haver com esse assunto.

 O que devo fazer para resolver este problema?

Comment: Não seria `VALUES (?, ?)`?

Comment: @bfavaretto, pode explicar porque? Estou com dificuldades. Sei que %s é para string e %d é para integer.

Comment: @bfavaretto, está-me a dar este erro com a sua sugestão. ProgrammingError: You must not use 8-bit bytestrings unless you use a text_factory that can interpret 8-bit bytestrings (like text_factory = str). It is highly recommended that you instead just switch your application to Unicode strings.

Comment: Esse erro parece ser causado por algum dado, deve ser um dos nomes, provavelmente algo acentuado. Sobre por que usar como eu falei, vi na [documentação](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute).

Comment: @bfavaretto, está-me a dar este erro com a sua sugestão. ProgrammingError: You must not use 8-bit bytestrings unless you use a text_factory that can interpret 8-bit bytestrings (like text_factory = str). It is highly recommended that you instead just switch your application to Unicode strings

Comment: Então, esse é que parece ser causado por uma questão de encoding/strings com acentos. Deixo pra outra pessoa opinar, não sou especialista nem em python nem em sqlite.

Comment: O nome que estava a usar continha um c de cedilha, ç.
Bastou mudar para c.

Answer (score 0):

No Sql, asinformações são separadas por ponto e virgula. `;`

```
INSERT INTO reciclagem_data (personID, nome) VALUES (%s,%s)
('Valor1','valor3')
('Valor2','valor3')
('Valor3','valor3')
```

verifique em seu envio se por 
uma de suas palavras não foi assim:

```
 ('Va'lor4','val'or4'),
```

No Sql nao vai!